# p-dataTable of primeNG counldnt fetch value from an array of employess /Angular4

Tags: angular, primeng, angular4-forms

It didn't display data of 
    `[value]="targetEmployeeonpopup"` in html
when ts file like:

```
  targetEmployeeonpopup: Employees[]=[]; 
  this.targetEmployeeonpopup.push({ uid: "aa",
          firstName: "aa",
          lastName: "aa",
          supervisorInd: true});
```

It displays when ts is:

```
 this.targetEmployeeonpopup=[{ uid: "aa",
          firstName: "aa",
          lastName: "aa",
          supervisorInd: true}];
```

May I get feedback on any reason for the problem?

Comment: When are you doing the push? OnInit?

Comment: yes it is in oninit, when the table is loading

Comment: Please add code style to questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you are facing is because of optimisation reasons on the table.

I believe the table is optimised to only work with detection strategy `OnPush`.

Meaning it won’t detect inner changes of objects (mutation). When you do a `push` you are mutating the object and not creating a new reference.

Try doing the same thing but using the `spread operator` instead.

Something like:

```
this.targetEmployeeonpopup = [...this.targetEmployeeonpopup,{ uid: "aa", firstName: "aa", lastName: "aa", supervisorInd: true}];
```

The `spread operator` will create a new object with the new elements. That will trigger Angular change detection on the table. Because it’s not mutating the original object.

Comment: Glad to help. Did you understand the reason? :)

Comment: Good. Always happy to help.